# How to use UpgradeComponent to a AngularJS directive that uses $attrs in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, typescript, ng-upgrade

Currently I have this `.directive` in AngularJS:

```js
aegroApp.directive('poorLegacy', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      hasSomething: '=?',
      anotherBinding: '@',
    },
    controller,
    templateUrl: function (_, attrs) {
      return attrs.hasSomething ? 'file.html' : 'file2.html';
    },
  }
});

function controller($attrs, /* others */) {
  // perform some checks with $attrs
  // rest of the code
}
```

and I'm trying to use [**UpgradeComponent**](https://angular.io/api/upgrade/static/UpgradeComponent) to be able to use this in Angular:

```
@Directive({ selector: 'my-bridge' })
export class MyBridgeDirective extends UpgradeComponent {
  @Input() hasSomething?: boolean;
  @Input() anotherBinding?: string;

  constructor(elementRef: ElementRef, injector: Injector) {
    super('poorLegacy', elementRef, injector);
  }
}
```

```html
<my-bridge [hasSomething]="false"></my-bridge>
```

But it fails... and the reason is explained [**here**](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6715#issuecomment-331996391) (basically it doesn't support `$attrs`).

So, the question is: how could I use that legacy directive without rewriting this right now?